React code is ignoring changes made with useState (ReactJS)
So I have a case where I want to run an interval only if a variable, called isComplete, is false. I have isComplete tied to a state with useState and that seems to work fine. However, even when isComplete is set to true, the interval keeps getting set and it keeps going instead of stopping. This isn't all of the code as I'm simplified it down for this specific question (otherwise it'd be several pages long).
interface iStatus = {
    status: string,
    message: string,
    isComplete: boolean,
}

const defaultStatus: iStatus = {
  status: 'test',
  message: 'test message',
  isComplete: false,
}

const StatusComponent = () => {
   const [status, setStatus] = useState(defaultStatus);

   const checkStatus = () => {
       try {
           let tempStatus: iStatus = await getStatusFromServer() //Imported function that makes a backend call
           setStatus(tempStatus)
       } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
       } finally {
           if (!status.isComplete) {
               setTimeout(checkStatus, 2000); //Continue asking the backend until the status is good
           }
       }
   }

   useEffect(() => {
        checkStatus() //start checking the status on component mount
    }, [])

    return (<div>{status.message}</div>});
}

Basically, the issue is that whenever isComplete is set to true, the interval that checks it still think it's false and then sets another interval, which causes it to get stuck in an infinite loop regardless of what the backend server says. This is problematic because sometimes the backend server will change it's status from good to something else, and in that case I actually DON'T want to keep checking it; I want the interval to stop on the first success regardless of what the backend is doing.
A potential solution I did find was to put the setTimeout check in the try portion instead of finally (and remove finally altogether), but this results in the timeout not getting set if the call fails. If the call fails, I do want the timeout to get set because I want it to keep trying no matter what until it gets a successful call. If I try and remedy this by putting another setTimeout in the catch, it also causes a loop to happen and I have no idea why.

You have created a closure over the initial state by calling checkStatus() once on mount. You will either need to use the fetched tempStatus in your condition, or move the logic into the useEffect and make it dependent on your state.

The root of the problem is that React code you are writing is not the code browser is running.
Hooks such as useEffect or useState are read and transformed to another code, compatible for the browser to be run.
For example, when you run setIsComplete(true) line inside the checkStatus function, it does not change value of the variable isComplete , no.
It changes the state which could be read via isComplete variable.
That is the root difference.
And when you changes the state, React re-renders the component, and it runs useEffect again, which starts new timeout.
Because useEffect runs on each render, it's important to have cleanup function:
   const checkStatus = () => {
       // ...
-               setTimeout(checkStatus, 2000);
+               return setTimeout(checkStatus, 2000); // return timeout ID
       // ...
   }
   useEffect(() => {
-        checkStatus()
+        const timeoutId = checkStatus() // save ID of timeout
+        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId) // clear timeout on element deattach
    }, [])

and also it's important to track the state, which is involved in your logic:
   useEffect(() => {
        const timeoutId = checkStatus()
        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)
-    }, [])
+    }, [isComplete]) // run useEffect when isComplete is changed

That is just a quick fix of your infinite loop, it's not a solution for your issue in general, because with this fix it still checks status 3 times. I've posted this answer just to illustrate that usage of useEffect is a bit wrong.
It's very important to understand the lifecycle of React components.
P.S. My suggestion would be using React as UI library only, and do application logic outside the UI library, and bind UI to track specific parts of the state, changed by that application logic.
